# Have a data structure with unknown length

Tags: javascript

How to print this dynamically?

```
data = {
    "name": "EU",
    "size": 10,
    "nodes": [
        {
            "name": "England",
            "size": 2,
            "nodes": [
                {
                "name": "Center",
                "size": 1,
                "nodes": [
                        {
                        "name": "main street",
                        "size": 0.5,
                        "nodes": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                "name": "Vilage",
                "size": 1,
                "nodes": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Germany",
            "size": 4,
            "nodes": []
        }
    ]
}
```

and I need somehow dynamically print it like this

```
EU 10
EU - England 2
EU - England - Center 1
EU - England - Center - main street 0.5
EU - England - Vilage 1
EU - Germany 4
```

This is the code that i have closest what I need

```js
var data = { "name": "EU", "size": 10, "nodes": [ { "name": "England", "size": 2, "nodes": [ { "name": "Center", "size": 1, "nodes": [ { "name": "main street", "size": 0.5, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Vilage", "size": 1, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Germany", "size": 4, "nodes": [] } ] }


function printValues(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      printValues(obj[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}
printValues(data)
```

This is what I get

[image]

Comment: can you explain more about what printValues function does?

Comment: Need it in pure javascript or jquery atleast

Comment: I made you a snippet as you could have done to show a [mcve]. Please note I also removed all the waffle around the question. Most visitors are not really interested

Comment: printValues function is the function that calls it self out when done to go deepr if the value is object to dinamicly reach deper no mater how deep it goes,by the way thanks @mplungjan, new here at posting so dont know much functionality

Comment: *Dynamically, *recursive function

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were on the right track - you can indeed use recursion to walk the data structure. What you also need is to get the `name` property and build up a the start of each line from each `name` encountered. You can ferry that information using a second parameter to the recursive function. Then you need to recursively call the function for each child node and pass all the `name`s encountered so far:

```js
const data = { "name": "EU", "size": 10, "nodes": [ { "name": "England", "size": 2, "nodes": [ { "name": "Center", "size": 1, "nodes": [ { "name": "main street", "size": 0.5, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Vilage", "size": 1, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Germany", "size": 4, "nodes": [] } ] }


function printValues(data, prefix = []) {
  //make a copy of the prefix instead of mutating it
  let location = prefix.concat(data.name);
  console.log(location.join(" - "), data.size);

  data.nodes.forEach(child => printValues(child, location))
}

printValues(data)
```

Comment: Thanks dude, realy helped me out here, but now i need to know how to close thread with "solved problem" :D

Comment: @MrNeedHalpHere you should have [a grey tickbox under each answer's score](https://i.imgur.com/ly1PqRX.png) - you can click it to accept an answer. Feel free to choose that one that helped you the most, you are not obliged to accept the highest voted.

Answer (score 2):

Here what i got

```js
var data = { "name": "EU", "size": 10, "nodes": [ { "name": "England", "size": 2, "nodes": [ { "name": "Center", "size": 1, "nodes": [ { "name": "main street", "size": 0.5, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Vilage", "size": 1, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Germany", "size": 4, "nodes": [] } ] }

function printElem(str, element) {
  ret = str + " " + element.name + " " + element.size;
  console.log(ret);
  for (item of element.nodes) {
    printElem(str + " " + element.name, item);
  }
}

printElem("", data);
```

Comment: you're welcome !  don't forget to close this topic then

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```js
var data = { "name": "EU", "size": 10, "nodes": [ { "name": "England", "size": 2, "nodes": [ { "name": "Center", "size": 1, "nodes": [ { "name": "main street", "size": 0.5, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Vilage", "size": 1, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Germany", "size": 4, "nodes": [] } ] }

function printValues(data, prepend) {
  console.log(prepend + data.name + ' ' + data.size);
  prepend = prepend + data.name + ' - ';
  for (node of data.nodes) {
    printValues(node, prepend)
  }
}
printValues(data, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use recursion on the nodes list:
I'm outputting the results with console.log.
Changed thanks to comment by VLAZ.

```js
var data = { "name": "EU", "size": 10, "nodes": [ { "name": "England", "size": 2, "nodes": [ { "name": "Center", "size": 1, "nodes": [ { "name": "main street", "size": 0.5, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Vilage", "size": 1, "nodes": [] } ] }, { "name": "Germany", "size": 4, "nodes": [] } ] }


function printValues(prefix,obj) {
  if (typeof obj !== "object") return;
  prefix = prefix?(prefix+" - "+obj.name) : obj.name;
  console.log(prefix+" "+obj.size);
  for (var key in obj.nodes) {
      printValues(prefix,obj.nodes[key]);        
  }       
}

printValues("",data);
```

Comment: You can just put the `typeof obj !== "object"` guard at the start of the function instead of doing that check to decide whether to recursively call again or not. That's usually how recursive functions terminate - they just shove whatever looks like the next step as the parameter to the recursive call and guard against the wrong input at the start. Works better if as it both protects against calling with something like `printValues("", null)` as well as signaling what the termination condition is.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over the visited names and iterate the nodes.

```js
const
    getItems = (parts = []) => ({ name, size, nodes = []}) => {
        console.log(`${parts.concat(name).join(' - ')} ${size}`)
        nodes.forEach(getItems(parts.concat(name)));
    };

var data = { name: "EU", size: 10, nodes: [{ name: "England", size: 2, nodes: [{ name: "Center", size: 1, nodes: [{ name: "main street", size: 0.5, nodes: [] }] }, { name: "Vilage", size: 1, nodes: [] }] }, { name: "Germany", size: 4, nodes: [] }] };

getItems()(data);
```

Comment: Nope. Cannot read this sufficiently well to understand it. `{ name, size, nodes = []}) =>` is destructuring, right? How does `nodes.forEach(getItems(parts.concat(name))` work, there is one one node in each object, no?

Comment: Sure it works, Just my mind cannot grasp it as usual with Nina Code ;)

Comment: @mplungjan `nodes.forEach(getItems(parts.concat(name))` works even though there is a single node only because `getItems(getItems(parts.concat(name))` only expects a single object to be passed in and `.forEach` will pass each object through the function. That way you don't have to handle an array or non-array differently - you only deal with non-arrays. You can also just call `getItems(parts.concat(name))(nodes[0])` which will do the same thing but since `nodes` is an array you might actually have more items there, and `nodes[0]` will skip the rest.